# Froala Editor 2 basic init Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

I just follow froala documentation and mix it with current layout using metronic.

Here is my css order.

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/global/css/components-md.css" id="style_components" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/global/css/plugins-md.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/admin/layout2/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="assets/admin/layout2/css/themes/grey.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color"/>
<link href="assets/admin/layout2/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/coeg-editor/css/froala_editor.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/coeg-editor/css/froala_style.min.css" />
```

and here is my JS order

```
<script src="assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/global/plugins/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/global/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/global/scripts/metronic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/admin/layout2/scripts/layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/coeg-editor/js/froala_editor.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
   Metronic.init(); // init metronic core componets
   Layout.init(); // init layout
   $('a[href="{{ Request::url() }}"]').parent().addClass('active');
   $('textarea#content').editable({inlineMode: false});
});
</script>
```

and I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` right at the `$('textarea#content').editable({inlineMode: false});`

But there is no error if I comment `$('textarea#content').editable({inlineMode: false});` section.

How I can fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/v2.0/docs/migrate-from-v1 for using 
froalaEditor()
instead of
editable()

never mind the html which contain example still using v1 syntax instead of v2 :D